# Как добавить точку и другие способы реализации первой заглавной буквы?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> На вход Вашей функции будет передано одно предложение. Необходимо вернуть его исправленную копию так, чтобы оно всегда начиналось с большой буквы и заканчивалось точкой.

```
def correct_sentence(text ) -> str:
    """
        returns a corrected sentence which starts with a capital letter
        and ends with a dot.
    """
    for i in text:
...     return i.lower().capitalize()
...     

    # your code here
    return text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(correct_sentence("greetings, friends"))

    # These "asserts" are used for self-checking and not for an auto-testing
    assert correct_sentence("greetings, friends") == "Greetings, friends."
    assert correct_sentence("Greetings, friends") == "Greetings, friends."
    assert correct_sentence("Greetings, friends.") == "Greetings, friends."
    assert correct_sentence("hi") == "Hi."
    assert correct_sentence("welcome to New York") == "Welcome to New York."

    print("Coding complete? Click 'Check' to earn cool rewards!")*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот один из вариантов решения Вашей задачи:

```py
def correct_sentence(text ) -> str:
    """
        returns a corrected sentence which starts with a capital letter
        and ends with a dot.
    """
    text = text[0].upper() + text[1:]
    if(text[-1] != '.'):
        text += '.'

    return text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(correct_sentence("greetings, friends"))

    # These "asserts" are used for self-checking and not for an auto-testing
    assert correct_sentence("greetings, friends") == "Greetings, friends."
    assert correct_sentence("Greetings, friends") == "Greetings, friends."
    assert correct_sentence("Greetings, friends.") == "Greetings, friends."
    assert correct_sentence("hi") == "Hi."
    assert correct_sentence("welcome to New York") == "Welcome to New York."

    print("Coding complete? Click 'Check' to earn cool rewards!")*
```

Что здесь происходит:

1. Изначальному тексту присваивается его первый символ в верхнем регистре (если уже был в верхнем, так и останется) и этот символ конкатенируется с оставшимся текстом
2. Если последний (-1ый) символ текста не точка, к тексту добавляется точка